# How can irrational numbers be written as decimals

Tags: fractions, irrational-numbers

It is commonly stated that irrational numbers can be written as decimals. But the thing is, the decimal would have to be infinite in length.

So why can an irrational number be written as a decimal if one is not able to complete it?

Thanks!

Comment: You can approximate irrational numbers by a sequence of rational numbers, each with a terminating expansion. You should also give meaning to $10^\infty.$ (Spoiler: there is no meaning.)

Comment: Okay, perhaps irrational numbers cannot be written as a fraction, but then how can it be written as a decimal?

Comment: @SeanRoberson, I was thinking it could be a number with 1 and an infinite amount of zeros after? I don't know if that can exist in math

Comment: Infinity is not a number. You can't raise $10$ to $\infty$. And $10^{\text{length of decimal}}$ can only work if $\text{length of decimal}$ is finite.  To talk of raising things to infinite powers when it is clearly non-sense and to expect it to work because somehow it's a bunch of tricksy-wordsy is not how math, law, english, or thought works.

Comment: " but then how can it be written as a decimal? "  It can't.  You'd run out of paper and space in the universe to write it down.

Comment: But then why do people say that irrational numbers can be written as a decimal?

Comment: We approximate irrational numbers by terminating decimals. Again, look at continued fractions.

Comment: Unless you consider writing for eternity as "writing a decimal",  an irrational number can only be _approximately_ written as a decimal. I suggest that those who "commonly state" are simplifying for practical purposes, ignoring the approximation involved.

Comment: We don't actually say we *can* write it as a decimal.  We say if we *could* express it as a decimal it would need an infinite number of decimal places.

Comment: Can you write $\frac{1}{3}$ as a decimal? It would have to be infinite in length. Same thing, except the decimal expansion is periodic.

Comment: "Irrational numbers can be written as decimals"? Not literally! You can't even write every finite integer as a decimal, in practice. Try writing out all the digits of a googleplex some time -- you'll run out of ink and hardly even have gotten started. Irrational numbers have decimal *representations*, but that requires that you define the limit of an infinite series *despite* the fact that you can never actually write every term all in one place.

Answer (score 3):

Not only can we not write irrational numbers as decimals, depending on what you consider to be a valid "decimal", **we can't even write all rational numbers as a decimal**.
$$
\frac{1}{9} = 0.111111.... = 0.\overline{1}
$$
do you consider the right-most expression a valid decimal? All it really is, is a shorthand notation for telling you how you could start writing down a sequence of decimal numbers that approximate the rational number ${\frac{1}{9}}$.

The same is true for irrational numbers, but the rules for approximating them via decimals is (mostly) more complicated than approximating rationals via decimals. Rational numbers will eventually repeat themselves in decimal notation, and any decimal that eventually keeps repeating will be rational. For example,
$$
0.1122453453274\overline{231}
$$
I can tell you will be rational without any further calculation simply because it ends with a repeating sequence of ${231231231231....}$. Irrational numbers **will not** eventually keep repeating themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ be a real number. When we say *$x$ can be written as a decimal*, it means there exists an integer $N$ and a sequence $(a_{k})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of *digits*, elements of $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$, such that
$$
x = N + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{k}}{10^{k}}
= N + \sup_{n \geq 1} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{a_{k}}{10^{k}}.
$$
If $x$ is irrational, this representation is unique. (The situation is slightly more complicated for rationals with terminating decimal expansion: To get a unique representation, we must pick between a representation ending in an infinite string of $9$s or an infinite string of $0$s, as in $1.0\overline{0} = 0.9\overline{9}$.)

What seems to be bothering you (and if so, you are not alone!) is that we cannot in general know all the digits $(a_{k})$.

If $x$ is is the limit of some known sequence of rational numbers, such as roots of rational polynomials, or $\pi$, or $e$, or *insert your favorite irrational number here* (unless you have especially esoteric favorites), then we can in principle calculate as many of the $a_{k}$ as we want.

To address your question:

Since any two calculating entities will arrive at the same sequence of digits of a particular irrational $x$, the digits of $x$ *exist*. (Or if you prefer, *...it's convenient to speak of the digits of $x$ as if they exist.*)

Since each such sequence $(a_{k})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ defines a unique real number by the "completeness axiom", any infinite decimal represents a real number.